# Como faço para adicionar uma animação enquanto esta carregando um requisição do Angular 4?

Tags: typescript, angular

Meu serviço esta assim:

```
export class ServicoService {

    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    public listar() {
        return this.http.get('aqui a url')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
    }

}
```

O código esta funcionando corretamente, porem gostaria de dar um Feedback para o usuário dizendo que o conteúdo esta sendo carregado. Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode estender o serviço Http do Angular para interceptar suas chamadas assíncronas exibindo ao usuário uma tela de carregamento ou aguarde por exemplo.

Você pode encontrar uma implementação nesse [gist](https://gist.github.com/LincolnLuiz/4d882bffe66683c11bf90b3233f041e5)